# No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}' - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object, types

I read key value pairs from a file, the key is string and the value is {r,g,b} numbers.

colorNames.json file:

```
{
  "name1": { "r": 151, "g": 23, "b": 26 },
  "name2": { "r": 62, "g": 137, "b": 32 },
  "name3": { "r": 13, "g": 31, "b": 62 },
}
```

```
fetch("/colorNames.json")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) => {
    colorsNames = data;
  });
```

when i pass the value to a function I get this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.

```
for (let key in colorsNames) {
    let distance = getDistance(color, colorsNames[key]);
}
```

```
function getDistance(
    color: { r: number; g: number; b: number },
    match: { r: number; g: number; b: number }
  )
```

Also, what is the correct way to declare colorsNames as?

```
var colorsNames: object;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `colorsNames` to have a `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) so that you are allowed to index into it with any `string`-valued key.  Like this:

```
const colorsNames: { [k: string]: { r: number, g: number, b: number } } = {
    "name1": { "r": 151, "g": 23, "b": 26 },
    "name2": { "r": 62, "g": 137, "b": 32 },
    "name3": { "r": 13, "g": 31, "b": 62 },
};
```

Here you're saying that at every property whose key is of type `string`, you have a value of type `{r: number, g: number, b: number}` (which you might want to give a name to, like `interface Color {r: number, g: number, b: number}`, but that's a digression).

Now you can iterate over its properties as desired:

```
for (let key in colorsNames) {
    let distance = getDistance(color, colorsNames[key]); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2IBOEByBDAtgUwgLhgG8YBtAawOiQEswBzAXQOKQLAFdMAjbJAGhh02nHvxhdh3XjAC+smAF4iAKACQAIjBZsARnXMY6pPpg6ArDoHq6JgEwBmK1zsA2WXzWbttk8SMmXWysbAh17AHYnE3tbd08tHHtfQ2NQx0MQmHtLQ2cCQLiZAG5lZQATbGB4dCRsGAAzdjBgKGpwQWwoABFqaHRm7AAKNQRkA1YYDikxIUmRXgEJOem41Ux0KGAAC3HJUQFZqf3xPekZZQBKU6QS8srq2rhwaCfECZZrg8+T5dFZUvqyBgg3gnRgZGwAE8YLRXsg0NoIBcVKpQbAyr0oP1gHUlHROj0+gNBqMxKSETgIOQoQwLkUYAB6BkwEBkdCQ5QyIA)

Comment: Thanks.I am new to TypeScript, I was suspecting that declaring `colorsNames` as `object` is not going to cut it. Yeah, I should use interface for that.